# Android Camera App based on timer

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to implement an app that continues to take pictures every 5 seconds after the user presses a button. Here is my full code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAutoCamera extends Activity {
    private Camera camera; // camera object
    private TextView textTimeLeft; // time left field
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textTimeLeft=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTimeLeft); //make time left object
        camera = Camera.open();
        SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder()); // feed dummy surface to surface
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.startPreview(); 
    }


    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallBack=new Camera.PictureCallback() {      
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // set file destination and file name
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            path += "/AutoPictures/myPicture.jpg";//***
            File file = new File(path);//***

            //File destination=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myPicture.jpg");
            try {
                Bitmap userImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                // set file out stream
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);//**
                //FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                // set compress format quality and stream
                userImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);        

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    public void startTimer(View v){

        // 5000ms=5s at intervals of 1000ms=1s so that means it lasts 5 seconds
        new CountDownTimer(5000,1000){

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // count finished
                textTimeLeft.setText("Picture Taken");
                camera.takePicture(null, null, null, jpegCallBack);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // every time 1 second passes
                textTimeLeft.setText("Seconds Left: "+millisUntilFinished/1000);
            }

        }.start();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_auto_camera, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyAutoCamera" >


    <Button 
        android:id ="@+id/buttonStartTimer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text= "Start Timer"
        android:onClick="startTimer"/>

    <TextView
        android:id ="@+id/textTimeLeft"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the Permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My problem is:

1. After the app is displaying Picture taken, i am unable to find the picture in my storage. I have created on my device a folder called AutoPictures.
2. How can i modify the code above to continue to take pictures every 5 seconds and not just one picture?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After you add a file to the file system in order to make it visible when connecting to your storage run this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(exportFile);
intent.setData(uri);
ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

As for continuing to take pictures there are many ways to do it, Handler, Timer, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, AsyncTask etc...
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You should generate the files names (time based?) so they won't over write.

Comment: Didn't Work. The picture still doesn't show up. My problem is not with the Media Scanner, because I have rebooted my device after adding the file so that the Media scanner can find it.

Comment: Try removing the .getAbsolutePath() - I have similar code that works without, but if I don't call the MEDIA_SCANNER the file won't appear. Otherwise I don't have a better idea.